# I need to receive a message from HC 06 bluetooth module to Bluetooth terminal app

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am usng pic 16f877a and Hc 06 bluetooth module to recieve a string to android app called Bluetooth terminal. I am recieving some flags with question marks that have no frequency or rythm of recieving. i need to configure that to recieve string to that app. can some one help me solving this. thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <xc.h>
#pragma config=0x2F0A
#define _XTAL_FREQ  8000000
#define BAUDRATE 9600
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "usart_pic16.h"
#include <math.h>
// BEGIN CONFIG
#pragma config FOSC = HS
#pragma config WDTE = OFF
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF
#pragma config BOREN = ON
#pragma config LVP = OFF
#pragma config CPD = OFF
#pragma config WRT = OFF
#pragma config CP = OFF

void InitUART(void) {
   BRGH = 1;
   SPBRG = ((_XTAL_FREQ/16)/BAUDRATE) -1 ;
   TRISC6 = 0; // TX Pin
   TRISC7 = 1; // RX Pin 
   TXSTA = 0x24;
   RCSTA = 0x90;
   //SPBRG  = 51;
}
// Writes a character to the serial port
void SendByteSerially(unsigned char Byte) {
   if(!TXIF) ; // wait for previous transmission to finish
   TXREG = Byte;
}
// Reads a character from the serial port
unsigned char ReceiveByteSerially(void) {
   while(!RCIF)
   continue;   // Wait for transmission to receive
   return RCREG;
}

void SendStringSerially(const unsigned char* st) {
   if(*st)
      SendByteSerially(*st++);
}

void ReceiveByteSerially(const unsigned char* st) {
   while(*st)
      ReceiveByteSerially(*st++);




void main (void) {

   InitUART(); // Intialize UART

   while(1){
   SendStringSerially("Hello World");
}
```

Comment: Must be baudrate issue. have you set same baudrate at both microcontroller and bluetooth module?

Comment: yes i have the same!!